# c# vlc activex dynamic playlist from folder

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, dynamic, vlc, playlist

I am writing a winform application with VLX activex plugin.

I want the VLC player to play all files within a folder.

The folder can be updated so whenever a file is put into folder , I want that file to be added to the playlist as well without any user interference.

What are my options in doing this ?

Comment: do you know how to manually build the playlist? if so, what you need is just an event handler to update your list whenever a new file got uploaded.

Comment: I know how to do it manually but to do so I need to give file path , and I dont know how to get the file path dynamically

Comment: have a check of the FileSystemWatcher: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx